# Error ejecutando Cython -> unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

Buenas! Cuando intento ejecutar un archivo con Cython me aparece el siguiente error:

```
G:\>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'VF_n' extensión
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Estoy usando Python 3.5.1 en Windows 7, 64 bits

Ya he instalado el Visual Studio como aparecía en una respuesta a una pregunta similar y persiste el problema.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Qué VS has instalado? Cómo has instalado Python (python.org, conda/anaconda)? Necesitas VS2015 ya que CPython 3.5 se compila con él.

Comment: @kikocorreoso Gracias Kiko. He instalado la última versión de [VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs). He instalado Python a través de Anaconda

Comment: y cython lo has instalado usando **conda** o **pip**? Lo has instalado en un **conda-env** o en un **virtualenv**? Estás ejecutando `python setup.py...` en el mismo 'sitio' en el que está instalado cython? Independientemente de todo lo anterior, cython, hoy en día, tiene wheels y si instalas con pip o conda no haría falta visual studio ya que los [conda packages o los wheels ya vienen compilados](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/). A lo mejor el problema viene en el setup.py o en la respuesta a alguna de las preguntas de este comentario

Comment: Gracias @kikocorreoso Instalé Cython usando conda en un conda-env y no estoy ejecutando `python setup.py ...` donde he instalado Cython. Ya he hecho lo de `pip install (full path to the .whl file)` empleando el .whl de Cython tal como lo decía un comment del stackoverflow en inglés. Miro el comentario con calma e intento ejecutarlo en el "sitio" donde tengo Cython y en otra máquina por si acaso . Ya os comento mañana que tal!

Comment: Dices que has instalado la última versión de VS, ¿pero te has asegurado también de que estuviera activado el componente "Common Tools for Visual C++"?

Comment: Gracias @ChemaCortes Acabo de ver [acá](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/)  que cuando instalas el VS _If you choose “Typical”, then you can’t use Visual Studio to develop in C++, because only managed languages and web development tools will be installed_ Así que veo si lo puedo actualizar o lo instalo de nuevo. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: @ChemaCortes he instalado el common tools y ya no aparece el error! Ahora aparece otro relacionado a numpy que intentaré resolverlo. Gracias a ti y a @kikocorreoso! Saludos

Comment: Me alegro. Te sugiero que *autocontestes* tu pregunta con la solución que has obtenido para que así otros puedan encontrarla cuando la necesiten.

Comment: @ChemaCortes listo!

Answer (score 2):

SOLUCION:

El problema se resuelve activando el componente "Common Tools for Visual C++" en el Visual Studio. Si va a instalar el Visual Studio debe hacerlo de forma manual y seleccionar dicho componente. Si ya tiene instalado Visual Studio seleccionar New Project y en Visual C++ seleccionar el componente a instalar.

Saludos y gracias!